# Non parametric anova or two non parametric ttest?

Tags: anova, t-test, nonparametric, paired-data

I have a statistical question about a project I recently got.
We performed a flow cytometry assay on 3 different groups: controls (n=5), patients before treatment (n=5) and paired patients after treatment (n=5).

My plan would be to compare the median expression of the same cell population in controls and patients before treatment using an unpaired non parametric t-test and to compare the median expression of the same cell population in patients before and after treatment using a paired non parametric t-test. Is this correct or should I use ANOVA? In case I should use ANOVA how do I handle the fact that some comparisons are paired and some are not?

Comment: What are your research questions? What do you want to confirm/claim/reject?

Comment: What was the purpose of the control group? Why only baseline values there?

Comment: These are human samples, you cannot treat healthy people. This is why for the control group I do not have any treatment data. Guess the question we want to ask is if there are differences in the expression of certain markers between patients and healthy people and what is the effect of treatment on patients.

Comment: @Rosella: They your analysis strategy looks fine up to the fact that median tests will have too low power with $n = 5$, at least in the paired case. I didn't mean to treat the control group but to measure their "response" a second time, exactly as in the treatment group.

Comment: It's not just power! With a permutation test and 5 pairs the lowest possible p-value would be 1/32 (for a one-tailed test) or 1/16 (for a two tailed test). With such small sample sizes nonparametric tests become impractical unless you're willing to lift your type I error rate. Yet presumably you know something about how the quantity you're measuring will be distributed (it's not like nobody's performed these assays before) before you even see your data (such as any tendency to discreteness or skewness, for example). As such choosing a reasonable parametric model may be your best alternative.

Comment: I wasn't planning to perform a permutation test. Most of the papers I have seen compare the means of MFI (mean fluorescence intensity which is most cases is the median or geometric mean of the fluorescence of cells in a population) across distinct groups. They usually test for differences in mean (using t-test or Anova) but the value they use to compute the test for each sample is not a single measurement but  the median or geometric mean of thousands of cells.